# How do I handle error: couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier:... ARKit, assets problem

Tags: augmented-reality

XCode13.4.1, I got the following error, but I have no asset called car.

`UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier:`

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite a lot of googling to comeuppance with a solution.

I solved my problem by adding the Assets.xcassets to the build phase of the target.
[image]